# Shared preferences removing the first entered value

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm currently working on my app and I use shared preferences. The use of it works and how its applied.  When it saves my info it replaces the first entered value with the second set of info. Is there a way to save multiple values in one shared preferences file?

Comment: This depends on the information and how you want to manage it. If you need to get more complex with that is stored in a single key you can look at Parcelables.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is a key-value store, similar to a Java Map object. This means that for each key you can store only one value.

One SharedPreferences file can contain many keys though.

If you are storing a limited number of items with a single key, you could do some simple serialization such as putting the values in a single comma separated String.

For more lengthy lists of information you might want to consider a SQLite database or your own file-based storage method.

Answer (score 0):

If the second set of value is replacing the first set, that probably means you're saving the second set with the exact same key as the first set.

Try saving the second set of value with a different key:

```java
editor.putString("key1", value1);
editor.putString("key2", value2);
editor.apply(); // Or commit, whichever suits your need
```

---

Update examples

```
int counter = 0;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // If you want to use username as key and password as value
        saveUsernameAsKey();

        // If you just want to use a different key everytime you click,
        // you could try using a counter
        // This will use key "Username0", "Username1", "Username2"...
        saveUsername("Username" + counter);
        counter++;
    }
});

public void saveUsernameAsKey() { 
    userPref = getSharedPreferences("MyUsernames", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEnterUserName);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEnterPassword);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userPref.edit();
    editor.putString(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
}

public void saveUsernames(String usernameKey) { 
    userPref = getSharedPreferences("MyUsernames", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEnterUserName);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userPref.edit();
    editor.putString(usernameKey, username.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: I don't completely know how to say this.  I'm saving passwords in a shared preferences file and I don't know how many keys this will have.  When I save them I use the same key but how would I change the key in code?

Comment: Update: I don't think shared preferences is the place you want if you are looking to store your password - it's very risky to store password on your device. That being said, a simple way to do it is to use the username as key, and the corresponding password as the value.

I don't see a lot of use for this, however, unless this is for a simple class project. You definitely want a more secure mean to save your password.

Comment: public void SaveUsernames() {
        userPref = getSharedPreferences("MyUsernames", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        EditText Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEnterUserName);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userPref.edit();
        editor.putString("Usernames", Username.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();
    }I call this method to save the username when a button is clicked.  How do I change the key after clicking the button?

Comment: You can pass in the key as a parameter instead of hard-coded value, and changed it in your onClick method before you pass it in.

Comment: Could you send an example of that, I get what your saying, but I can't write it out.

Comment: Updated with examples